# netbeans subversion cleanup button

Tags: svn, netbeans, menu

There is a **cleanup** button in svn-workbench

Using it + update we can usually fix some svn bugs (for example "... is not a working directory")

I cant find this function in netbeans:
**context menu -> subversion**
and in the
**team -> subversion**

where is it?

upd:
I have not in the context menu "Cleanup Working Copy" item (netbeans 6.8 under ubuntu)

Comment: better fit to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have it in the context menu "Cleanup Working Copy"

Comment: If it's not there in 6.8 and is there in 6.9, I guess that quite obvious solution comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated netbeans to 6.9 version
"Cleanup Working Copy" appear at proper place!

**Mchl** comment is the right answer!
I dont understand him havent posted it as an real answer